# How can i align my div columns in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an image below to show what i mean. I need the pink Main Content column to move to where the black line is. the code is in the link below, I've tried all sorts and i need it to remain a responsive website.

Image: http://prntscr.com/51xf1t

Please find the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/xhwdzs32/ `.`

Comment: You can try changing the padding on your #content CSS to `padding:1% 2% 1% 1%;` See my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/0yywhgg8/

Comment: @AndrewHotovy changing padding will disturb the content, it's a bad UX design.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the margins and padding on the content div to this:

```
#content {
    float: left;
    margin: 1% 0% 1% 2%;
    padding: 0% 1%;
    background-color: #FFF0F5;
    width: 68%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/xhwdzs32/5/

Comment: adding padding difference will disturb the consistency

Comment: Look at the fiddle it doesn't @DanielCheung

Comment: if you fill the content with "x x x ...", you will see the problem. It's best to not add the padding

Comment: Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/xhwdzs32/7/ this is with X's and no change

Comment: What about it @DanielCheung

Comment: Are you talking about the line height? @DanielCheung

Comment: the PADDING! http://jsfiddle.net/xhwdzs32/9/ It's not balanced. It's a bad UX design.

Answer (score 0):

### Fix: Switching the margin-right with width

```
#content {
    width: 69%;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Though you can do it multiple ways, including changing paddings, like the other answer. Or even be safer to add a `float:right` to the div, **but** this is the best bet as it will create the minimum disturbance of the whole design, **keeping everything in consistency**.

Answer (score 0):

Change these 3 lines:

```
#content {
   float:right;
   margin:1% 0 1% 1%;
   width:69%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xhwdzs32/6/